# Using completionHandler to return a print when classifying an image in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, ibm-cloud, artificial-intelligence

I am new to Swift and am following a tutorial on how to develop an image recognition app for IOS. I believe I am close to finishing but I keep getting an error in Xcode saying "Missing argument for parameter 'completionHandler' in the call.

I have read the other threads about this error but don't know how to apply the tips to my own code. I am currently using 'success:' to tell the app to return the image classifications if there is a successful identification but from what I've read on the internet, this should be done with completionHandler.

My code is below and I would appreciate some advice on how to get around my issue.

```
import UIKit
import VisualRecognitionV3

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    let apiKey = "plxmWfJup7nEkQOwFUTPt9AVMGNd-RYoNK8TLTM_lxq6"
    let version = "26-01-19"



    @IBOutlet weak var cameraButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        imagePicker.delegate = self
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

        if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {

            imageView.image = image

            imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

            let visualRecognition = VisualRecognition(version: version, apiKey: apiKey)

            let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

            let jpegData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.01)

            let fileURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("tempImage.jpg")

            try? jpegData?.write(to: fileURL, options: [])

            visualRecognition.classify(imageFile: fileURL, success: { (classifiedImages) -> Void in
                print(classifiedImages)
            })

        }
        else{
            print("There was an error picking the image")
        }
    }

    @IBAction func cameraTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

        imagePicker.sourceType = .savedPhotosAlbum
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false

        present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

I'm also relatively new to stack overflow so I apologise if I haven't inserted my code right.

Thank you.

EDIT:

I solved this using the following code:

```
 if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {

        imageView.image = image

        imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        let visualRecognition = VisualRecognition(version: version, apiKey: apiKey)

        let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

        let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5)

        let imageURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("tempImage.jpg")

        try? imageData?.write(to: imageURL, options: [])

        visualRecognition.classify(imagesFile: imageURL) { response, error in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            }
            guard let classifiedImages = response?.result else {
                print("Failed to classify the image")
                return
            }
            let classes = classifiedImages.images.first!.classifiers.first!.classes

            for index in 0..<classes.count{
                self.classificationResults.append(classes[index].className)
            }

            print(self.classificationResults)

            if self.classificationResults.contains("hotdog"){
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.navigationItem.title = "Hotdog!"
                }
            }
            else{
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.navigationItem.title = "Not Hotdog!"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func cameraTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    imagePicker.sourceType = .savedPhotosAlbum
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = false

    present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)


}
```

Comment: How do they document the call to visualRecognition.classify ?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by that. The original code doesn't contain the "-> Void" after (classifiedImages) by the way.

Comment: Found this on https://forums.swift.org/t/incorrect-argument-label-in-call/14889/3: classify(image:success:) method on VisualRecognition expects an instance of UIImage as its first parameter. You pass a URL. So, I was asking how is the API (function declaration) defined in VisualRecognition doc ?

Comment: There seem to be also an API with URL:  visualRecognition.classify(url: url, failure: failure) { classifiedImages in print(classifiedImages) ; syntax is a bit different to yours. See (in French): https://console.bluemix.net/docs/swift/machine_learning/recognition.html#recognition

Comment: Thank you for those links, I think the first one is following the same tutorial, unfortunately it doesn't come to a definitive answer. I will keep trying to change the syntax and maybe use the failure and URL types instead.

Comment: It looks like your call to `visualRecognition.classify` is different then what is expected. I think it should be `visualRecognition.classify(imagesFile: fileURL, acceptLanguage: nil, url: nil, threshold: nil, owners: nil, classifierIDs: nil, imagesFileContentType: nil, headers: nil) { (restResponse, watsonError) in
                print(watsonError)
            }`

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I solved the problem as in the post edit! I appreciate the point in the right direction though!